# Which URL do I use to "COMPLETE" a PayPal transaction on the SagePay simulator?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, opayo

A client of ours want's to handle PayPal transactions via SagePay,

I've got the initial request working to set up the transaction and redirect off to PayPal via:
https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/VSPDirectGateway.asp

But this doesn't seem to work for "COMPLETE"-ing the transaction, in test mode you'd use:
https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/complete.vsp

or in production:
https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/complete.vsp

But how would I complete the request in the simulator? the first URL doesn't seem to work -

`You have sent a TxType of COMPLETE which is not recognised.`

Neither does https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/VSPServerGateway.asp?Service=VendorCompleteTx -

`Server Simulator reqires a Service Name as part of it's URL. e.g. VSPServerGateway.asp?Service=VendorRegisterTx. This service tells Server which tasks to perform.`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one? https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/paypalcomplete.asp

Let me know.